# Accessing members of a struct that is received by reference

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reference

Hi I have a few doubts about how to access the members of a struct, in case that the struct is recived by reference by some function.

here is a program that generates a random "image" and have 2 examples of my problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define WIDTH 16
#define HEIGHT 8

typedef struct
{
    int width;   
    int height; 
    int maxvalue;
    char *pixels;
} image;


void setimagemaxvalue (image *img)
{

    scanf ("%d", &((*img).maxvalue); //I know is wrong 

}

void createimage (image *img) //just creates a random matrix of pixels
{
        (*img).pixels=malloc((img->width)*(img->height));

        int i,j;

    char *tmp;
    tmp=(*img).pixels;

    for (i=0;i<(img->height);i++)
        {
        for (j=0;j<(img->width);j++)
        {
            *(tmp+(i*(img->width)+j))=(char)(rand()%(img->maxvalue));
        }

    }   

}



int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    image img;

    img.width=WIDTH;
    img.height=HEIGHT;

    setimagemaxvalue(&img);
    createimage (&img);

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1) What should be the parameter send to the scanf function?
(forget about the buffer cleaning issue, and yes, I know that I can just send the maxvalue member of the struct to the "setimagemaxvalue" function, but this is just an example, I want to know how to do it considering that it's a member of a struct.

2) How could I write the function "createimage" without using the tmp variable (there is the pointer img referencing  the pointer pixels and it's referencing the data).

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) About the parameter of scanf

```
scanf ("%d", &((*img).maxvalue));
```

is right way to read the value.
Alternatively you can also use

```
scanf ("%d", &(img->maxvalue));
```

Similarly you can replace `(*img).pixels` with `img->pixels` if you think later is more readable.

2) You can replace all occurances of `tmp` with `img->pixels`

Comment: I see about the scanf there was a parenthesis mising, but I thinked it was wrong because it seems weird to me using an asteric and an ampersand in the same sentence, now I know its not.
and for the tmp yeah, it works great, thanks!

Comment: You used an asteric to dereference an object of type `struct image` and used an ampersand to get the address of type `int` so it should be fine. You need both of them and can not skip these both without some tricks.

Answer (score -1):

You start by writing: 'received by reference.' , but you are actually passing you struct by pointer.
Others have showed that you can use -> which is the correct way to address members when using pointer.

But I think in your case (looking at main) you would be better of passing by reference instead.
e.g.

```
void setimagemaxvalue (image &img)
{
    scanf ("%d", &(img.maxvalue);
}
```

that way you can use . instead of ->
and in your main it would look like this:

```
image img;
....

setimagemaxvalue( img );
```

No ampersand in front of img

Best regards
Asger-P

Comment: There are no references in C.

Comment: @Asger-P I think you are wrong, in this way I am sending a struct to a function who expects a pointer, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Ubs, must have been sleeping, sorry.